# Importing posts via MySql (a csv file) need to be automatically published

Tags: import

I'm importing a csv file via the database, all the posts are unpublished when I look in the CMS, is there a way to make them automatically published on import?

Doing a bulk publish via the CMS doesn't work as I need the dates I've put in the CSV file to be the publish date, not the date publish was clicked.

In the post_status column, all the posts are set to publish.

I'm trying to import hundreds of posts of news and the dates need to be in the past.

Here's my csv file:

```
ID  post_author post_date   post_date_gmt   post_content    post_title  post_excerpt    post_status comment_status  ping_status post_password   post_name   to_ping pinged  post_modified   post_modified_gmt   post_content_filtered   post_parent guid    menu_order  post_type   post_mime_type  comment_count
6000    1   13/09/2010 00:00    13/09/2010 00:00    "Content here"  New Report Available - Taking Medical Sensing Technologies to Market        publish open    open        new-report-available-taking-medical-sensing-technologies-to-market          13/09/2010 00:00    13/09/2010 00:00        0   http://www.mediwales.com/v3/?post_type=news&#038;p=6000 0   news        0
```

[image]

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to import via MySQL? I'd imagine that the `post_status` simply needs to be set to `publish`?

Comment: @dunc Sorry, added to the question that the post_status is publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions for what you can try:
Try to remove the empty columns, especially post_excerpt. 
Try another import plugin.
Try another delimiter.

Comment: I just get an invalid column count error when deleting empty columns.

Comment: Tried several csv plugins which don't seem to work.

Comment: What does the data look like in the database (after the import)?

Comment: It won't import because of the error.

Comment: You already imported some data, what does that data looks like? You can make a select * from your posts table or you can use a database tool to open up that table.

Comment: The dates just revert to the time it was imported.

Comment: And the other fields? You need to look in the mysql database.

Comment: Aha! Got it! Sorry, took me a while to see but now I can see why you kept questioning the database. The date was in the wrong format - it needed to be yyyy-mm-dd mm:hh

Comment: You solved it yourself, glad I pushed you in the right direction :)